# How to check content of button with JS in if function

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, button

I'm trying to check if button contains certain string when I click on it, and if it contains, for example "text1" I want to replace it with "text2" and vice versa.
Thank you in advance.

Edit:
To simplify everything, how can I change the text of button if it contains certain word when I click on it.

Here is the sample code:

```
<html>
<body>
   <button id="btn">text1</button>
   <p id="result"></p>
   <script>
      let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      let content = btn.innerHTML;

      document.getElementById("btn").onClick=function(){
          if(content.trim()==="text1"){
      document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML ="text2";
          } 
      }
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question are you asking about while clicking you want to replace the data with other string?

Comment: `content` does not keep updating when you change the text.

Comment: I'm new with JS so sorry for trouble, when i click on button i want to change text of the button with another text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should toggle the button text as expected. The `content` variable does not update.

```html
<html>
<body>
   <button id="btn">text1</button>
   <p id="result"></p>
   <script>
      let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      let content = btn.innerHTML;
      
      document.getElementById("btn").onclick=function(e){
          const content = e.target.innerHTML
          
          if (content === "text1") {
            e.target.innerHTML = "text2"
          } else {
            e.target.innerHTML = "text1"
          }
      }
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the event to an eventlistener and switch the text on click.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btn.innerHTML = { text1: 'text2', text2: 'text1' }[btn.innerHTML];
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">text1</button>
```

Comment: It's amazing!!!